# org-capture prompt for headline after content

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I want to create a capture template for my org-based journal. But I do not want to worry about entering a title straight away.

How can I setup my capture template so that `org-capture` prompts me for the title only after I finish writing my journal entry?

Thanks!